# WSO2 IS different 'mail.smtp.from' per tenant?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we are running WSO2 IS 5.3.0 with multiple tenants. The question is can we specify a different email smtp configuration per tenant such as the 'mail.smtp.from'?

It appears like there is only one file in the IS server for configuring email 'from' address in:

```
<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/output-event-adapters.xml
```

and the 'mail.smtp.from' from there gets applied to all outbound emails sent from IS, no ability to change this per tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, above requirement is not supported at the moment by WSO2 IS 5.3.0. Sender email configuration is common for all the emails. We don't have such a configuration to set sender email configuration for each tenant. We have to do some code level customization to achieve your requirement.